# import users from other file than realm during startup using docker-compose

Tags: keycloak

I have a `my-realm.json` defining a keycloak realm. In our dev environment, we also have a `my-realm-users.json` that defines some test users for `my-realm`. They both refer to the same realm.

In the dev environment, we would like to import both files, but this would not work:

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1
    environment:
      # ...
    volumes:
      - ./my-realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/my-realm.json
      - ./my-realm-users.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/my-realm-users.json
    command: ['start-dev --import-realm']
```

It does not work - only the `my-realm-users.json` is imported. As far as I understand, the `my-realm-users.json` is found first in the folder, it is imported and creates the realm. The `my-realm.json` is then found, but skipped because the realm already exists.

How can we keep the files separated but import the test users after creating the realm? We do not want to do it by hand, but we need it to be automatically done when starting the keycloak image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we ended up doing is to have a setup script that merges the two json files using `jq` ( see https://jqlang.github.io/jq/ ):

```
jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; .users += $i.users)' my-realm.json my-realm-users.json > gen/my-realm-with-users.json
```

It takes two input files

- `my-realm.json`
- `my-realm-users.json`

and generates one output file:

- `gen/my-realm-with-users.json`

We then import the generated file:

```
   volumes:
      - ./gen/my-realm-with-users.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/my-realm.json
```

PS: on ubuntu you can install jq via `sudo apt-get install jq`